# display elements in one line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display two elements in one line.
What i have used i thought it would work without a issue, but unfortunately it is 
not. But instead this is what i am getting:

```css
div#inline{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
    
}

input[id="Prod_name"]{
width: 90%;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: auto;
}

label#label{
float:right;
padding-right: 40px;

}

p#session{
padding-left: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
line-height:28px;
    
}

input[id="list_ord"]{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 5%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div id='inline'>
  <p>Menu Item</p>
  <label id='label' for='list_ord'>List Order</label>
  <input type='text' id='list_ord' name='list_ord' value=''>
  </div>
```

I need the  list order label, list order text and the menu item text to be on one line.
I have used both inline and display-inline. Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: label and input are in 1 line, so which 2 is not?

Comment: @LGSon i should have been more specific. I also need the menu item p tag in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div#inline{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
    
}

.inline{
  display:inline-block;  
}

input[id="Prod_name"]{
width: 90%;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: auto;
}

label#label{
float:right;
padding-right: 40px;

}

p#session{
padding-left: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
line-height:28px;
    
}

input[id="list_ord"]{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 5%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='inline'>
  <p class='inline'>Menu Item</p>
  <label id='label' for='list_ord'>List Order</label>
  <input type='text' id='list_ord' name='list_ord' value=''>
  </div>
```

You need to give the paragraph element that has the text, Menu Item, `display:inline-block;` too.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you